# How can I enforce that my urls always start with www?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, url, rewrite

I want to ensure that users come to `www.mydomain.com` even if they arrive through the alias `mydomain.com`. This is so that I have control over cookies on subdomains, and so that Google sees one single domain and not a hodge-podge of URLs.

How can I do this with apache?

Comment: Might I suggest you instead reverse this, and enforce mydomain.com instead?  The 'www' prefix is redundant and entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Cookies are sent to all subdomains on mydomain.com, while I can decide for myself what cookies are loaded from where with www.mydomain.com.. For instance, I can avoid adding cookies to static.mydomain.com, so that cookies aren't transmitted for every image that is loaded. It is definately not unnecessary.

Comment: You can specifically tell Google to use a single linking style. See my answer below.

Comment: I don't have the rep, but adding these tags would be helpful: redirect redirectmatch mod_alias

Comment: Even though this is _much_ later, it's still relevant. www is __not__ deprecated, because a domain with no subdomain has several disadvantages. See http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/ for several reasons to use www.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
   ServerName domain.com
   RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com

   ... usual config
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For a slightly simpler solution, you can: "Redirect permanent / ptth://www.domain.com/" and apache will automatically preserve the suffix. (I reversed http to disable the autolink.)

Comment: Really ? Sweet, I never knew that. I always thought you had to use RedirectMatch to preserve the trailing parts of the URI

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `httpd.conf` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Enable mod_rewrite support then create a .htaccess file in the root folder for you domain with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: don't forget to make the RewriteCond test case-insensitive...

Comment: Only do this if you don't have access to make changes to the apache config file for some reason.  `.htaccess` files have a lot of overhead, and rewrites inside them make it much worse.

Comment: using Redirect is always preferable to using mod_rewrite for this task.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want Google to use a specific domain style (with or without *www*) then create a free [**Google Webmaster Tools**](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/siteoverview) account, verify the ownership of your domain (upload a file) and set your [preferred domain](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231) using the online control panel.

Its that simple, and you don't need to change any server side code, also inbound links with or without *www* will be treated the same increasing the PageRank of your pages.

> Links may point to your site using
>   both the www and non-www versions of
>   the URL (for instance,
>   http://www.example.com and
>   http://example.com). The preferred
>   domain is the version that you want
>   used for your site in the search
>   **results**.
>
> Once you tell us your preferred domain
>   name, we'll take your preference into account when
>   displaying the URLs. It may take some
>   time before you see this change fully
>   reflected in our index.
>
> If you **don't** specify a preferred domain,
>   we may treat the www and
>   non-www versions of the domain as
>   separate references to separate pages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite problem, people going to www.domain.com when I just want to serve directly from domain.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com

   ... usual config
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ServerAlias sub.domain.com # can also catch some other subdomains
   ServerAlias *.domain.com # or all previously unmatched domains

   Redirect permanent / http://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

As Greg Hewgill mentioned, using Redirect is a bit simpler than RedirectMatch and does the same job, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect for more details.