# How to i setup DNS and Web so that Mac OS X Server 10.6 displays a webpage under http://domain.net instead of http://www.domain.net

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, mac-osx-server

How to i setup DNS and Web so that Mac OS X Server 10.6 displays a webpage under http://domain.net instead of http://www.domain.net

www is fast becoming deprecated with people forgetting to add it. Some browsers add it and some don't.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you neeed to have

1. Dns records for www.domain.net and
   domain.net to point your server
2. You need to have (i assume apache is
   default on mac server) on your
   virtualhost config/section also
   DomainAlias.

   ```
   ServerAdmin admin@domain.net

   ServerName domain.net

   ServerAlias www.domain.net domain.com www.domain.com

   DocumentRoot /home/sivu/public
   ```

That way your server will hand over site were it requested with or without www.

Not sure where you can actually manage configuration on mac os x server. If you have default configuration (this site is (maybe only) default site). Then you don't have to do anything else than #1. In linux environment those config files can be found from /etc/apache2/sites-available. Mac prob have some control-panel for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at these similar questions.

- [How can I enforce that my urls always start with www?](https://serverfault.com/questions/446/how-can-i-enforce-that-my-urls-always-start-with-www)
- [Redirect all non-www subdomains to main www domain with Apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/66313/redirect-all-non-www-subdomains-to-main-www-domain-with-apache2)

Comment: I want to have it the other way around. I want the www domains to point to the empty root domain.

Comment: Regardless of which canonical form you prefer, you use the same techniques to enforce it.